# Speeding up creation of NSDictionary from XML?

Tags: cocoa

I need to speed up the creation of NSDictionary from XML(of size larger thar 25 Mb), is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please add code to show what you're doing.

Comment: You are not providing any information, like how long it is taking now, if it is an XML plist using the builting deserializer or a custom XML file you have your own parser for, etc.

Comment: I am using the following code 
 NSDictionary *XMLDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:XMLFilePath];

While performing this operation my system is hanging and processor usage is maximum...

Answer (score 0):

Make smaller files. Other than that, no, there is nothing you can do to make that method any faster.

If the size of the plists is unavoidable, you can move the loading and processing into operations or onto an explicit thread to avoid blocking your UI while you and your user wait.